# Is there a method to strip specific letter form a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a method to strip specific letter form a string? I want to strip some letters from a string. For example, strip `a=` from `a=alpha` and strip `b=` from `b=bravo`. I have tried the normal strip method but the output would be `lph` and `ravo` while the targets are `alpha` and `bravo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.replace()` method.
Documentation - https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Eg.

```
>>>a = "a=alpha"
>>>a.replace("a=", "")
'alpha'
```

Comment: Wow, perfect solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that this won't behave like `strip()` as it would replace `'a='` from any part of string.

Comment: @Austin OK, I see

Comment: Be aware this is only working because it's being done in the shell, if you're not working in a shell you need to assign the copy that `replace` produces to another variable, or `a` will not change. (for example `a_new = a.replace("a=", "")`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make sure that 'a=' and 'b=' is stripped only from the beginning of the string, you have to use pattern matching, e.g.:

```
import re
re.sub('^[^=]*=','','a=alpha')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use split like this:

```
x = "a=alpha"

x.split("=")[1]
```